# Shopify API: Create a Promotion?

Tags: shopify

Using the Shopify API, is there a way to creation promotions for your store?  If not, is there a way to programmatically create promotions in Shopify? (short of using CURL posts to the admin)

That is, I can create a promotion by hand using the admin and navigating to the `Promotions` and clicking the `Add a discount code` link.  I'd like to be able to do the same thing programmatically, or to know for certain this isn't possible.  I don't see any obvious method on the [api list](http://api.shopify.com/), but it seems like something should be an API method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately they don't allow it... I resorted to creating an interface to do so, though:

https://github.com/MartinAmps/Shopify-Private-APIs

Hope it helps

**Edit**

I also created a [blog post](http://ma.rtin.so/reverse-engineering-shopify-private-apis) about it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to create discounts via the API.

If you want we have made an [application that can be used to create discount codes](http://apps.shopify.com/bulk-discounts).

Otherwise you can use a tool like Mechanize to automate coupon creation for you, but keep in mind theres a good chance that any time in the future it will break since we don't make any promises to keep our admin the same in the future.  Any changes have a good chance of breaking whatever script you'd end up writing.

Comment: Chris, any reason for this? There's obviously already an API made for managing discounts, as it's being used by
http://docs.shopify.com/manual/more/official-shopify-apps/bulk-discounts
(The Bulk Discounts app requires some time to generate all of the discount codes in your store because it works with Shopify's robust API to generate codes. The API has a call limit imposed on it)

Answer (score 2):

The Price Rules API is now public and allow any app to create price rules and discount codes.

https://help.shopify.com/api/price-rules

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with `Rails` or you're already using `ActiveResource` for your Shopify API calls, then you can drop in this modified version of `Discount < ActiveResource::Base` https://gist.github.com/choonkeat/09a56da222f506e627c5