# Shopify discounts via API

Tags: shopify

I noticed /admin/discounts.json works when logged into the store admin but from the API it isn't supported. I am using a private app not a full app store one, if that makes a difference. Any way to allow it to work from an API login as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shopify API: Create a Promotion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242989/shopify-api-create-a-promotion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discounts are currently not supported via the API, see this answer for more detail:
[Shopify API: Create a Promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242989/shopify-api-create-a-promotion)