# Create Discount Code using Shopify API?

Tags: shopify

I'm currently trying to determine if there is a way to add discount codes via the shopify API.

I found this question from last year where it was not possible through the API but could be achieved with a custom script (i'd like to avoid this sort of hack if possible):
[Shopify API: Create a Promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242989/shopify-api-create-a-promotion)

According to this post it was supposed to be a feature coming soon:
http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apps/t/is-there-an-api-for-coupon-codes-47500

Is this API feature now available, is it still in the works or has it been abandoned altogether?

Comment: No. That API is not publicly available

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shopify API: Create a Promotion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242989/shopify-api-create-a-promotion)

Answer (score 3):

To all those coming here, Shopify has recently developed an endpoint to create discount codes and price rules.

[Price Rule](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/pricerule)

[Discount Code](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/discountcode)

Answer (score 3):

```
$shop = ShopifyApp::shop();

    if( $shopSettings->discount_id == '' || $shopSettings->discount_id == null || $shopSettings->discount_id == undefined ) {

        $price_rule = $shop->api()->rest(
            'POST',
            '/admin/price_rules.json',
            [
                "price_rule" => [
                    "title" => "SUMMERSALE10OFF",
                    "target_type" => "line_item",
                    "target_selection" => "all",
                    "allocation_method" => "across",
                    "value_type" => "percentage",
                    "value" => "-"+request('discount_percentage'),
                    "customer_selection" => "all",
                    "starts_at" => "2017-01-19T17:59:10Z"
                ]
            ]
        );

        $shopSettings->price_rule_id = $price_rule->body->price_rule->id;

        $discount_code = $shop->api()->rest(
            'POST',
            '/admin/price_rules/'.$price_rule->body->price_rule->id.'/discount_codes.json',
            [
                "discount_code" => [
                    "code" => $price_rule->body->price_rule->title
                ]
            ]
        );

        $shopSettings->discount_id = $discount_code->body->discount_code->id;

    } else if( request('discount_percentage') && request('discount_type') == "percentage" ) {

        $price_rule = $shop->api()->rest(
            'POST',
            '/admin/price_rules/'.$shopSettings->price_rule_id.'.json',
            [
                "price_rule" => [
                    "value" => "-"+request('discount_percentage')
                ]
            ]
        );

    }
```

Answer (score -3):

Shopify offers a free App to make and manage discount codes. Install that and use it since it is as good as hacking in codes with scripting.