# Shopify API - get discount codes in the store with PHP

Tags: php, shopify

With a Shopify API call I am able to get the product data, but I need a way to get the discount codes available in the store.

I need the script in PHP. Does anyone have an idea of how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these similar questions will help you get started:

- [Shopify API: Create a Promotion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242989/shopify-api-create-a-promotion)
- [Discount API](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/discount-api-196067)
- [How do I get the Discount information from Shopify in C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919170/how-do-i-get-the-discount-information-from-shopify-in-c-net)

The first 2 links above mention [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/MartinAmps/Shopify-Private-APIs). It provides an example you might be able to use:

```
require 'shopify.php';
$api = new \Shopify\PrivateAPI('username', 'password', 'https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin');

...

$discounts = $api->doRequest('GET', 'discounts.json', $params);
if (isset($discounts->discounts)) {
    $coupons = $discounts->discounts;
    foreach ($coupons as $coupon) {
        print_r($coupon);
    }
}
```